# Ошибка сегментации

Tags: c

Код выдаёт ошибку сегментации, но не могу понять, почему. Думаю, всё из-за структуры, подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct User {
    char login[16];
    char IP[15];
};

int main() {
    char mask[11];
    printf("Input mask: ");
    scanf("%s", mask);
    printf("The mask is %s\nInput number of users: ", mask);
    short N;
    scanf("%d", N);
    struct User users[100];
    // char name[16];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        // scanf("%s ", name); 
        scanf("%s %s", users[i].login, users[i].IP);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        printf("%s %s", users[i].login, users[i].IP);
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема наверняка в

```
scanf("%d", N);
```

[На самом деле](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) нужно

```
scanf("%hd", &N);
```

Из-за двух грубых ошибок ваш код пишет в какую-то не принадлежащую вам память.

Comment: @VladD, а замеитли, что последнее время в вопросах новичков очень часто пишут *`short`*, а не "де факто стандартный" *`int`*?

Интересно, с чего бы это?

Comment: @avp: Хм, и правда. Может, вышла новая книжка? Или у нас наплыв людей из одного и того же вуза?

Comment: память экономят.

Comment: @VladD, наверное второе. 

А преподаватель (или методичка к лабам) базируется как раз на какой-то старой книжке, когда память еще эконмили.

Comment: @KoVadim, думаете их самих (новичков) одновременно посетила такая идея?

Comment: пардон, какая разница??
К & B пишут short, если я иду по их книге, почему бы и мне не писать short?
если из авторитетных учебников этот наиболее популярен, то разве не  понятно, "с чего бы это?"

Comment: @mrexox: Формально, никакой разницы нет. Фактически, принято использовать `int`, если у вас нет строгой необходимости в другом (огромный массив и надо экономить память, или наоборот размера `int` не хватает).

Comment: @mrexox, хотите сказать, что в книге K&R приведено много примеров программ, где вместо *int* (или *long*) используется *short*? 

--

Я ее очень давно не смотрел, но уверен, что это не так (может и есть парочка, но скорее всего демонстрирующих особенности "коротких" типов, а может и вовсе нет). 

А вот то, что они для индексов и размеров массивов используют *int* -- не сомневаюсь

(сейчас-то правильным для этих целей считается использовать `size_t` и/или `ssize_t`).

Comment: >А в K&R short?

Я вот тоже что-то не припомню обилия short в `K&R`, да и short вообще, сплошные инты.

>почему бы и мне не писать short?

Ну,  хотя бы потому, что экономии от него ноль (в случае переменных, а не массивов, short всё равно будет выравниваться, и, скорей всего, не на 2 байта, а больше). А работа эффективной всё-таки с int (да-да, уворачиваясь от летящих кирпичей с надписями "микрооптимизация" :-)